# How do you put a custom modal message within the ons-modal directive?

Tags: onsen-ui

```
<ons-modal var="modal">
    {{modalMsg}}
</ons-modal>
```

I tried the above code and then using scope.modalMsg to update the message before displaying the message but it didn't work. I found out that once it's 'declared' the message cannot be changed. It's like  whereby you can't put a scope value as the button name and have it changed dynamically while the code is running. Right now my hack is

```
<ons-modal var="modal">
    <div id="modalMsg"></div>
</ons-modal>
```

create a service that does $('#modalMsg').html(msg) where msg is my custom message. Anyone else has a proper angularJS way that doesn't touch the DOM from within the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a dynamic message inside an Onsen UI modal using AngularJS.

```
<ons-modal var="app.modal">
  <p>{{ data.message }}</p>
</ons-modal>
```

I made a small example:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/bGcvo

Whatever you put into the input element will be displayed in the modal.